# C# ChineseLunisolarCalendar for .netstandard

Tags: c#, calendar, .net-standard

I have a C# (.net framework) application that uses the ChineseLunisolarCalendar but this is not available on .net standard is there a other library available?

I have found nodatime but i think the chineselunarcalendar is not available on this library (http://nodatime.org/2.0.x/userguide/calendars)

Thanks Tom

Comment: NodaTime >= 2.0.0 is available for .net standard 1.3+, are you sure it doesn't work?

Comment: yes a coworker have check this. The support response: There's no support for it at the moment. The description in Wikipedia is somewhat disconcerting, in terms of "estimation" and the like. If there are fixed rules we can apply, it should be feasible.

Comment: I see, I mistook the question to be specific to NodaTime on .net standard. Sry!

Answer (score 0):

`ChineseLunisolarCalendar` is available through the `System.Globalization.Calendars` NuGet package for .NET Standard 1.3 and higher. For the upcoming .NET Standard 2.0, the reference to this NuGet package will no longer be needed.

You can add the package via the package management UI or via command line:

```
dotnet add package System.Data.Common
```